# How do you create a graffiti in Left 4 Dead 2?

Tags: team-fortress-2, left-4-dead-2, source-engine

I was playing Left 4 Dead 2 and I saw a player paint a graffiti on a wall (I also saw it done on Team Fortress 2)

How is this done? What is it purpose?

Is it different on those two games or is it something at the engine level?

Comment: This is called a "Spray" and is common to the source engine, I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The place you configure your sprays is in the options menu, under multiplayer.

[image]

From this place you can import an image of the proper dimensions, which will show up when you use the spray command (default <kbd>T</kbd>) in game.

Comment: It's my fault for asking technically two questions in one, but do you happen to know how it's done in L4D2 too?

Comment: @Juan - I don't know off hand, and since neither game is currently installed on my computers, I can't easily check for you.

Answer (score 3):

The default key for sprays is <kbd>T</kbd> in TF2.  It is likely the same in L4D, though if you look through the keyboard settings it should be there.

Bear in mind that some servers restrict sprays to avoid objectionable (porn or other shock) sprays.  If you're on such a server, when you attempt to throw up your spray, the noise will play but nothing will happen.

Comment: In my personal experience, I often have to double-tap T to get it to work.

Comment: It is generally very finicky, you might have to press it more than twice. But yes it's T by default.

Comment: But I can spray whatever I want? How does it work?